# Importing remote image to a canvas

Tags: javascript

How can the user import image and put it within a canvas using Javascript??
All the lessons I have seen focus on importing images from identified sources.
for example:

```
var img = new Image(); 

img.onload = function(){

};

img.src = 'myImage.png'; // Set source path
```

This is fine but if I want the user imports the image from his computer >>> is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The code for that is here: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/02/an-html5-offline-image-editor-and-uploader-application/

Comment: Hi I found this link >>>> very useful http://robertnyman.com/2011/03/10/using-html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-to-offer-the-cure/